# I am receiving the weather forecast data from an API(OpenWeatherAPI). I want to convert the UTC time to a string. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript

list
Array(40)
0
{dt: 1519074000, main: {…}, weather: Array(1), clouds: {…}, wind: {…}, …}
1
{dt: 1519084800, main: {…}, weather: Array(1), clouds: {…}, wind: {…}, …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what representation you need, the basic one is 
`new Date(ourData.list[1].dt).toString()`, which accepts milliseconds, in case your time is in seconds, then obviously `new Date(ourData.list[1].dt * 1000).toString()`

Comment: So this is my code ` var time = new Date(ourData.list[1].dt).toString() ` , The result I am getting is Sun Jan 18 1970 16:58:15 GMT+0300 . which is obviously not the expected value

Comment: Just a heads up that this Unix time is in seconds.  You need to multiply by 1000 to convert to milliseconds, which Date takes as an input.  For formatting dates, folks generally use a library like Moment or Datefns

Comment: @edwinwalela well "Sun Jan 18 1970 16:58:15 GMT+0300" looks pretty fine to me, it's a string not a Date Object, I couldn't know that you pass it in seconds, it's not in the description. Anyways, check out the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow https://www.epochconverter.com it has converter tool that converts the datetime stamp to human readable form. Hope this helps.